# Swift, error EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100695474)

Tags: swift, breakpoints, lldb

I'm trying to create a game in Swift (Xcode 6.4) and I'm getting this error:

> EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100695474)

In console:

> false
>   2015-08-02 11:14:35.248 Taxi Smash[3996:1485308] G 1019
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Screen: [image]

Continue of the log:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ():
0x100695448 <+0>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
0x10069544c <+4>:   mov    x29, sp
0x100695450 <+8>:   sub    sp, sp, #16
0x100695454 <+12>:  and    w8, w2, #0x1
0x100695458 <+16>:  tbnz   w8, #0, 0x100695478       ; <+48>
0x10069545c <+20>:  tbnz   x1, #63, 0x100695568      ; <+288>
0x100695460 <+24>:  add    x1, x0, x1
0x100695464 <+28>:  mov    x2, x3
0x100695468 <+32>:  mov    x3, x4
0x10069546c <+36>:  mov    x4, x5
0x100695470 <+40>:  bl     0x1006c5334               ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x100695474 <+44>:  brk    #0x1
0x100695478 <+48>:  str    xzr, [sp, #8]
0x10069547c <+52>:  cmp    x0, w0, uxtw
0x100695480 <+56>:  b.ne   0x100695620               ; <+472>
0x100695484 <+60>:  lsr    w8, w0, #11
0x100695488 <+64>:  cmp    w8, #27
0x10069548c <+68>:  b.ne   0x1006954b4               ; <+108>
0x100695490 <+72>:  adr    x0, #584602               ; "fatal error"
0x100695494 <+76>:  nop    
0x100695498 <+80>:  adr    x3, #586600               ; "high- and low-surrogate code points are not valid Unicode scalar values"
0x10069549c <+84>:  nop    
0x1006954a0 <+88>:  movz   w1, #0xb
0x1006954a4 <+92>:  orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x1006954a8 <+96>:  movz   w4, #0x47
0x1006954ac <+100>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x1006954b0 <+104>: bl     0x100695448               ; <+0>
0x1006954b4 <+108>: lsr    w10, w0, #16
0x1006954b8 <+112>: cmp    w10, #16
0x1006954bc <+116>: b.hi   0x1006954ec               ; <+164>
0x1006954c0 <+120>: cmp    w0, #128
0x1006954c4 <+124>: b.lo   0x100695510               ; <+200>
0x1006954c8 <+128>: orr    w8, wzr, #0x80
0x1006954cc <+132>: bfxil  x8, x0, #0, #6
0x1006954d0 <+136>: cmp    w0, #2047
0x1006954d4 <+140>: b.hi   0x10069558c               ; <+324>
0x1006954d8 <+144>: movz   x11, #0
0x1006954dc <+148>: movz   x10, #0
0x1006954e0 <+152>: lsr    w9, w0, #6
0x1006954e4 <+156>: orr    w9, w9, #0xffffffc0
0x1006954e8 <+160>: b      0x1006955e8               ; <+416>
0x1006954ec <+164>: adr    x0, #584510               ; "fatal error"
0x1006954f0 <+168>: nop    
0x1006954f4 <+172>: adr    x3, #586588               ; "value is outside of Unicode codespace"
0x1006954f8 <+176>: nop    
0x1006954fc <+180>: movz   w1, #0xb
0x100695500 <+184>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x100695504 <+188>: movz   w4, #0x25
0x100695508 <+192>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x10069550c <+196>: bl     0x100695448               ; <+0>
0x100695510 <+200>: movz   x10, #0
0x100695514 <+204>: movz   x9, #0
0x100695518 <+208>: mov    x8, x0
0x10069551c <+212>: orr    w11, wzr, #0x8
0x100695520 <+216>: umulh  x11, x9, x11
0x100695524 <+220>: cmp    xzr, x11
0x100695528 <+224>: cset   w11, ne
0x10069552c <+228>: tbnz   w11, #0, 0x100695620      ; <+472>
0x100695530 <+232>: lsl    x11, x9, #3
0x100695534 <+236>: cmp    x11, #63
0x100695538 <+240>: b.hi   0x100695624               ; <+476>
0x10069553c <+244>: and    x8, x8, #0xff
0x100695540 <+248>: lsl    x8, x8, x11
0x100695544 <+252>: orr    x8, x8, x10
0x100695548 <+256>: str    x8, [sp, #8]
0x10069554c <+260>: cmn    x9, #2
0x100695550 <+264>: b.le   0x100695568               ; <+288>
0x100695554 <+268>: add    x8, sp, #8
0x100695558 <+272>: add    x8, x9, x8
0x10069555c <+276>: add    x1, x8, #1
0x100695560 <+280>: add    x0, sp, #8
0x100695564 <+284>: b      0x100695464               ; <+28>
0x100695568 <+288>: adr    x0, #584386               ; "fatal error"
0x10069556c <+292>: nop    
0x100695570 <+296>: adr    x3, #584656               ; "UnsafeBufferPointer with negative count"
0x100695574 <+300>: nop    
0x100695578 <+304>: movz   w1, #0xb
0x10069557c <+308>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x100695580 <+312>: movz   w4, #0x27
0x100695584 <+316>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x100695588 <+320>: bl     0x100695448               ; <+0>
0x10069558c <+324>: orr    w9, wzr, #0xffffff80
0x100695590 <+328>: bfxil  w9, w0, #6, #6
0x100695594 <+332>: cbnz   w10, 0x1006955ac          ; <+356>
0x100695598 <+336>: movz   x11, #0
0x10069559c <+340>: movz   x12, #0
0x1006955a0 <+344>: lsr    w10, w0, #12
0x1006955a4 <+348>: orr    w10, w10, #0xffffffe0
0x1006955a8 <+352>: b      0x1006955d0               ; <+392>
0x1006955ac <+356>: lsr    w10, w0, #18
0x1006955b0 <+360>: orr    w11, w10, #0xf0
0x1006955b4 <+364>: cmp    w11, w11, uxtb
0x1006955b8 <+368>: b.ne   0x100695620               ; <+472>
0x1006955bc <+372>: orr    w10, wzr, #0xffffff80
0x1006955c0 <+376>: bfxil  w10, w0, #12, #6
0x1006955c4 <+380>: and    x12, x11, #0xff
0x1006955c8 <+384>: str    x12, [sp, #8]
0x1006955cc <+388>: orr    w11, wzr, #0x1
0x1006955d0 <+392>: and    x10, x10, #0xff
0x1006955d4 <+396>: lsl    x13, x11, #3
0x1006955d8 <+400>: lsl    x10, x10, x13
0x1006955dc <+404>: orr    x10, x10, x12
0x1006955e0 <+408>: str    x10, [sp, #8]
0x1006955e4 <+412>: add    x11, x11, #1
0x1006955e8 <+416>: orr    w12, wzr, #0x8
0x1006955ec <+420>: umulh  x12, x11, x12
0x1006955f0 <+424>: cmp    xzr, x12
0x1006955f4 <+428>: cset   w12, ne
0x1006955f8 <+432>: tbnz   w12, #0, 0x100695620      ; <+472>
0x1006955fc <+436>: lsl    x12, x11, #3
0x100695600 <+440>: cmp    x12, #64
0x100695604 <+444>: b.hs   0x100695624               ; <+476>
0x100695608 <+448>: and    x9, x9, #0xff
0x10069560c <+452>: lsl    x9, x9, x12
0x100695610 <+456>: orr    x10, x9, x10
0x100695614 <+460>: str    x10, [sp, #8]
0x100695618 <+464>: add    x9, x11, #1
0x10069561c <+468>: tbz    x9, #63, 0x10069551c      ; <+212>
0x100695620 <+472>: brk    #0x1
0x100695624 <+476>: adr    x0, #584198               ; "fatal error"
0x100695628 <+480>: nop    
0x10069562c <+484>: adr    x3, #584228               ; "shift amount is larger than type size in bits"
0x100695630 <+488>: nop    
0x100695634 <+492>: movz   w1, #0xb
0x100695638 <+496>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x10069563c <+500>: movz   w4, #0x2d
0x100695640 <+504>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x100695644 <+508>: bl     0x100695448               ; <+0>
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Show your code one step back in the stack trace

Comment: I forgot to connect storyboard to code... But thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your IBOutlets and if they are linked to your storyboard.

Comment: you should flag his answer as the correct answer @JiriSvec

Comment: Had this issue with a fetchedResultsController implementation - IBOutlet link was missing, works fine now

Comment: if my project is very large, how I am going to look that missing IBOutlet?

Comment: Generally it bugs when accessing a ViewController. You are in VC A and goes in VC B but you have the error while accessing B so just check your IBOutlets in the VC B @YestayMuratov

Answer (score 3):

Delete the derived data of your application.

`Xcode (top menu)` > `Preferences` > `Locations (tab)` > `Derived Data` gives you the path of the folder and simply trash the respective project folder inside that.

Also try cleaning your project if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This can have multiple causes. In my case, I was accidentally dividing by zero with CGFloats, so I got `+Infinite` in a variable and did some further calculations with it, which caused the crash.