# webview strong iboutlet in delegate is nil, awakefromnib never called

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, swift2

Currently converting an obj-c framework to swift.
In my delegate i have a class with an iboutlet to a webview (i defined it as strong) but when i try to set the url with (first block is from PhWebViewController):

```
var parent : PhFacebook?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: PhFacebook.self)
    self.window.title = bundle.localizedStringForKey("FBAuthWindowTitle", value: "", table: nil)
    self.cancelButton.title = bundle.localizedStringForKey("FBAuthWindowCancel", value: "", table: nil)
    self.window.delegate = self
    self.window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.FloatingWindowLevelKey))
}



var webViewController : PhWebViewController?
self.webViewController = PhWebViewController()
self.webViewController!.parent = self
self.webViewController!.webView .mainFrameURL = authURL
```

My osx app crash and xcode tells me it found nil while unwrapping an optionnal.
I have the same issue than his : 
[Swift, error EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100695474)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770556/swift-error-exc-breakpoint-code-1-subcode-0x100695474)

except that for me the iboutlet is connected with the strong attribute.
I did some check, the webViewController property is not nil but the webView is.
I thought the xib file might be corrupted so i created another one, made the outlets again but nothing changed.

Anybody had the same issue before?

Comment: You're assigning a new instance of `PhWebViewController` to `webViewController`. If you are referencing to the `IBOutlet` of `PhWebViewController` then it will crash because the outlet is nil (like the error says). That's because the view hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: Also on a side note, you probably want the `webViewController` to be `weak` to prevent a strong reference cycle.

Comment: So my awakefromnib method in PhWebViewController isn't called then.
That's weird as i didn't deviate from the original framework and the method isn't called in the code either and it works.

Comment: I have no experience with `awakeFromNib()` but I know the view hasn't been loaded yet when you're trying to access `.webView`. If `webViewController` serves as a delegate method, then you should set the delegate when creating this view *or* you could try to "find" the instance of `PhWebViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interesting by the answer, in order to load the xib file properly i used :

```
 NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("FacebookLogin", owner: self.webViewController, topLevelObjects: nil)
```